# Redmine, unable to checkout svn repository 401 failed

Tags: svn, redmine, svn-checkout

my problem is that i am unable to checkout repository, because of the authorization failed message, i used my redmine login/box root login and i can't checkout.
**i'm able to browse the repository from redmine without receiving any 404 errors.**
at the users link of the repository in redmine, no user is displayed, edited many time the repository user and still no progress.

i double checked the following
dsn at svn.conf from apache2 sites-available is correct
sql login , user and password are correct

server details
ubuntu 12.04
apache 2.2.22

Comment: Can you give us the exact command you're trying to run? 401 is an authorisation error, so something is wrong with either the request or the credentials you're providing.

Comment: i use tortoiseSVN, to checkout repository, the url looks like http://sub.domain.com/svn , it prompts for a username and a password, but can't login with any username or password. the tutorial that i followed is here http://grandslam90.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/howto-redmine-2-0-0-passenger-subversion-repositories-in-ubuntu-12-04/ all work until i setup svn and configure apache2 to user redmine DB/Pass for user authentication to repository.

Comment: i'm not sure, but the Redmine DSN/User/Pass that is configured at sites-available/svn.conf has nothing to do with user authentication in svn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure solved my problem. It allowed the repository to work integrated with Redmine (user mapping) and authenticated for SVN repository.
(Assuming you have Subversion's libapache2-svn packages and have restarted apache2 service)

create SVN parent directory

```
<pre>
mkdir /svn
</pre>
```

Open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf with an editor

```
<pre>
&#60;Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNParentPath /svn
 AuthType basic
 AuthName "SVN repositories"
 AuthUserFile /svn/auth
 Require valid-user
&#60;/Location>
</pre>
```

create htpasswd file and add a user, for adding just remove -c argument

```
<pre>
htpasswd -cm auth /svn/auth admin
</pre>
```

setup permissions

```
<pre>
chown -R www-data:www-data /svn
chmod -R g+ws /svn
</pre>
```

restart Apache

```
<pre>
service apache2 restart
</pre>
```

some changes also are needed in Redmine

```
<ul>
<li>Setup crontab for managing repositories with redmine</li>
<li>when you browse the repository from redmine and you get a 404 error then go to project settings-> repositories-> your repository [edit] 
<ul>
<li>Username = admin</li>
<li>Password is admin's password</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

you can browse/checkout/commit/etc from h..p://host/svn or via Redmine for browsing and use other tools like TortoiseSVN for checkout/commit/edit/etc..